# How can I check a date from a mysql database `2010-10-18 07:44:53` against a future date using PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how would my PHP code look like when I do this?

Comment: it would look beautiful (or at least as beautiful as php can be).

Comment: all I got right now is the value from the MySQL database which i used php and mysql

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. To pull records from a database? Boolean check once you have the date from a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$end = $now->modify('+1 year');
```

From @RC answer or, if you prefer, you can use one of this:

```
$end = $now->setTime(hours, mins, secs);
$end = $now->setDate(year, month, day);
```

Answer (score 1):

See UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and FROM_UNIXTIME() functions in the MySQL documentation.
See date() function in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

PHP > 5.2:

```
$start = new DateTime('2010-10-18 07:44:53'); // from MySQL
$now = new DateTime();                        // now 
$end = $now->modify('+1 year');               // now + 1 yr

if ($start > $end) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

([DateTime doc.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php))

or use mysql to calculate the difference between your future date and data date.

([mysql date and time functions doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html))

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime1 =$mysqlReturndate
$datetime2 = new DateTime('Future date');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

use diff() or date_diff()
```